List all automorphisms $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\alpha)$
List all automorphisms of the extension group
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},  \alpha)$$ where $ \alpha=cos(\frac{2\pi}{4}) + i sin(\frac{2\pi}{4})$
So I wrote the basis of the extension field:
{$1,\sqrt[4]{2}, \sqrt[4]{2}^2, \sqrt[4]{2}^3, \alpha, \alpha\sqrt[4]{2}, \alpha^2\sqrt[4]{2}^2,  \alpha^3\sqrt[4]{2}^3$}
I think there should be 8 automorphisms, right?
I ended up with 12 when i wrote all them all down (see picture).
How is that possible? Is my basis incorrect?


Are you sure you got $\alpha$ correct? As currently written, $\alpha=i$.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.
